# Springboot, Vaadin and RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, vaadin

I created a new project with spring boot that includes vaadin and springmvc.

I added a restcontroller class and a vaadin view class annotated with `@Route`, yet when trying to access the view I receive a blank pages and a lot of failed http request with 405 access code to `/VAADIN` and `/frontend` paths.

When removing the restcontroller, the vaadin view worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was adding a servlet mapping to the vaadin resources:

```
@WebServlet(
    urlPatterns = {
            "/VAADIN/*", "/frontend/*"
    },
    initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name = "productionMode", value = "false")
    })
public class MyServlet extends VaadinServlet {}
```

Don't forget to add `@ServletComponentScan` annotation.